# Pandas, create columns based on value in row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, mapping

I have the following dataframe (this is just one row):

```
X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8
32  23  17  0   3   24  9   14
```

I would like to map the value 14 in the column X8 to the following list `mylist`:

```
[ 0.06405287, -0.1176078 , -0.06206927,  0.08389127, -0.18036067,
        0.35158703, -0.0928449 , -0.0974429 , -0.06705306, -0.17196381,
       -0.03776502,  0.09204011,  0.47813812,  0.16258538,  0.2699648 ,
        0.07496626, -0.09791522, -0.31499937, -0.24898018,  0.06126055,
        0.13187763,  0.21042736, -0.1585868 ,  0.08355565, -0.13935572,
        0.12408883,  0.2043313 , -0.12544186, -0.09223691,  0.00720569]
```

For the sake of this question, here's a for loop that creates one dataframe.

```
col = {}
col['X8'] = {} #
col['X8']['14']= {} # just creating the double nest for the sake of the example, this would of course be 3 for loops because I need to match each unique value in each column to its corresponding list of 30 values
for i, x in mylist:
  col['X8']['14'][i] = x 

colx814 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(col['X8']['14'],orient='index').T
```

Now I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
0.064053    -0.117608   -0.062069   0.083891    -0.180361   0.351587    -0.092845   -0.097443   -0.067053   -0.171964   -0.037765   0.09204 0.478138    0.162585    0.269965    0.074966    -0.097915   -0.314999   -0.24898    0.061261    0.131878    0.210427    -0.158587   0.083556    -0.139356   0.124089    0.204331    -0.125442   -0.092237   0.007206
```

How do I join this to my original dataframe? My guess is map+apply+concat, but I'm not sure how to combine them effectively. Another solution would be to duplicate each column 30 times and then iterate+replace over each one? I searched and couldn't find an answer to this question, so I thought I'd post it in case someone had an answer, and if not answer it myself. This is what I'm looking for:

```
X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8 X8_0 X8_1 X8_2 ...etc
32  23  17  0   3   24  9   14 mylist[0] mylist[1] mylist[2] ...etc
```

Of course, each column would have its own 30 XN_n columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
weights = {}
for index, x in enumerate(encoded.columns):
  weights[x] = {}
  for id, val in enumerate(encoded[x].unique()):
    weights[x][val] = {}
    for weightid, weightval in enumerate(model_full.get_layer(embeddings[index]).get_weights()[0][id]):
      weights[x][val][weightid] = weightval

mappedembeddings = pd.DataFrame()
encodedindex = []
for row in encoded.iterrows():
  encodedindex.append(row[0])
  df0 = pd.DataFrame()
  for k, v in row[1].to_dict().items():
    names = []
    for z in weights[k][v].keys():
      names.append(str(k)+'_'+str(z))

    tempdf = pd.DataFrame([weights[k][v]])
    tempdf.columns = names
    df0 = pd.concat([df0,tempdf],axis=1)

  mappedembeddings = pd.concat([mappedembeddings,df0],axis=0)
  
mappedembeddings.index = encodedindex
```